# How to pass contents of other layout Views into presenter in onclick with data binding?

Tags: android, android-databinding

Basically, how do I do this:

```
android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(username.getText(), password.getText())}"
```

where username and password are EditText views in the layout whose contents I want to pass to the presenter. Is it necessary to set up two-way data binding to do this, or is there a way to refer to the contents of those other views within the layout?

I wonder if one way to do it is to enable two-way data binding and use a view model, e.g. LoginViewModel with fields for the username and password, set this as a variable on the, pass the whole thing to the login presenter when the form is submitted, and read it out of there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, you can access the text values from EditText because it supports two-way. You can do this:

```
android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(username.text, password.text)}"
```

Comment: Aha! Many thanks George. I wanted to pass String values so used this which worked beautifully: android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(username.text.toString, password.text.toString)}"

Comment: George, what are your thoughts about adding access (which means arbitrary method calls) to the views in the binding to the expression language? Seems like it would be easy to support, since the view binding class will already have public fields for the ID'd views.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable request. They wouldn't support change notifications, though.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to access the values ​​of the views within the layout itself using `Databinding`. The only way to do this is set these values inside variables in your layout file and access them using your presenter. eg:

**Activity:**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.your_layout);

    String username = mBinding.editText.getText().toString();
    String password = mBinding.editText.getText().toString();
    mBinding.setUserName(username);
    mBinding.setpassword(password);
  }
```

**Layout:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="name"
            type="java.lang.String" />

        <variable
            name="password"
            type="java.lang.String" />

       <Button
       android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(username, password)}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Not exactly** you are looking for **but yes there is a similar way**.

You can pass whole `EditText` in presenter and get a text from it.

```
android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(edtUsername, edtPassword)}"
```

and inside your presenter

```
public void login(EditText edtUsername, EditText edtPassword)
{

}
```

Comment: I should have said that in the project Android classes are banned in the presenter, so I cannot pass through the Views, only their string contents.

Comment: In that case directly pass string, try it with `android:onClick="@{()->presenter.login(edtUsername.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())}"`. This should work, i am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can access views in the same layout by their id:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username"
    ... />
<EditText android:id="@+id/password"
    ... />
<Button android:onClick="@{v->presenter.login(username.getText(), password.getText())}"
    ... />
```